# In AmChart map how to trigger event manually?

Tags: amcharts, ammap

In AmMap, "homeButtonClicked" event is present which got triggered when you click on home button.

I want to trigger that event manually.
Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Do you want to trigger the event OR trigger it's effect (fully zoom out)?

Comment: Event not full zoom out

Answer (score 1):

To completely zoom out the map, use [`zoomToSelectedObject()`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/AmMap#zoomToSelectedObject) ant pass in `map.dataProvider` as a parameter.

I.e.:

```
map.zoomToSelectedObject(map.dataProvider);
```

Working demo:

```js
var map = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "map",
  "dataProvider": {
    "map": "worldLow",
    "getAreasFromMap": true
  },
  "areasSettings": {
    "autoZoom": true
  }
} );

function zoomOut() {
  map.zoomToSelectedObject(map.dataProvider);
}
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/ammap.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/maps/js/worldLow.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Zoom Out" onclick="zoomOut();" />
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

---

To trigger an event on the map or any amCharts object for that matter, you can use `fire()` method. I.e.:

```
map.fire("homeButtonClicked", {
  type: "homeButtonClicked",
  chart: map
});
```

Here's a working example:

```js
var map = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "map",
  "dataProvider": {
    "map": "worldLow",
    "getAreasFromMap": true
  },
  "areasSettings": {
    "autoZoom": true
  }
} );

map.addListener("homeButtonClicked", function(event) {
  alert('homeButtonClicked');
});

function testEvent() {
  map.fire("homeButtonClicked", {
    type: "homeButtonClicked",
    chart: map
  });
}
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 280px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/ammap.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/maps/js/worldLow.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="trigger event" onclick="testEvent();" />
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Tried but failed with this exception - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at a.inherits.b.fire

Comment: Sorry, forgot one parameter for `fire()`. Updated the answer.

Comment: Sorry, But I want to trigger homeButtonClicked event from outside the map, which will bring map to home position

Comment: OK, so why did say the exact opposite to my comment question? :) I'm going to update the answer.

Comment: Neither example seem to work now when clicking on countries.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the code has changed since this was last answered. For me, this is what works.

```
map.clickMapObject(map.dataProvider)
```

Answer (score -1):

(For  martynasma) You still have an error on trigger event method (testEvent). Correct is:

```
map.fire({
    type: "homeButtonClicked",
    chart: map
  });
```